# Count content of columns in table symfony2/twig/doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

So I have this table created with a crud in my symfony2 project. The table displays different products with each their own price. I would like to have a output with the total value of all products at the bottom of the table.

index.html.twig of entity "waarde"

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}
<h1>Waarde voorraad</h1>

<table class="records_list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Fabriek</th>
            <th>Aantal</th>
            <th>Prijs</th>
            <th>Inkoop Waarde</th>
            <th>Verkoop Waarde</th>
            <th>Locatie</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
             <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getNaam() }}</td>
             <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getType() }}</td>
             <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getFabriek() }}</td>
             <td>{{ entity.aantal }}</td>
             <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getInkoopprijs() }}</td>
             <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getInkoopprijs() * entity.aantal }}</td>
             <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getVerkoopprijs() * entity.aantal }}</td>
             <td>{{ entity.getLocatie().getLocatienaam() }}</td>
            <td>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path('waarde_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">show</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path('waarde_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">edit</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

    <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('waarde_new') }}">
            Create a new entry
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

I have a association between the entities "Product" and "Waarde"(=value).

```
<td>{{ entity.getProduct().getInkoopprijs() }}</td>
```

The code above returns the price of a product. I already have done a simple code to calculate the value of a single product by this code ("aantal" = quantity/amount of products)

```
 <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getInkoopprijs() * entity.aantal }}</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% set sum = 0 %}

{% for entity in entities %}

    {% set sum = sum + (entity.getProduct().getInkoopprijs() * entity.aantal) %}

{% endfor %}

Total price: {{ sum }}
```

Comment: Thanks! Had to remove the each in "endforeach" but I see you already changed it